# encrypting/decrypting entire files

Tags: python, encryption

I'm not entirely sure how to edit this code for the answer.

Modify the scripts of Projects 1 and 2 to encrypt and decrypt entire files of text.

An example of the program interface is shown below:

```
Enter the input file name: encrypted.txt
Enter the output file name: a
Enter the distance value: 3
```

Decrypt.py:

```
"""
File: decrypt.py
Project 4.3

Decypts a file of encrypted text. and prints
the result.  The other input is the distance value.
"""

code = input("Enter the input file name: ")
output = input("Enter the output file name: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
plainText = ''
for ch in code:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue - distance
    if cipherValue < ord('a'):
        cipherValue = ord('z') - (distance - \
                                  (ordValue - ord('a')) - 1)
    plainText +=  chr(cipherValue)
print (plainText)
```

Encrypt.py:

```
"""
File: encrypt.py
Project 4.3

Encypts a text file.  The inputs are the names of
the input file and the output file and the distance value.
The encrypted code is witten to a new file.
"""

plainText = input("Enter a one-word, lowercase message: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
code = ""
for ch in plainText:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue + distance
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - \
                      (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
    code +=  chr(cipherValue)
print(code)
```

Comment: For the encryption case the smallest change would be to iterate over text read in from a file rather than the text in `plainText` obtained via `input`.

Answer (score 0):

before ask question read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page.

encrypt:

```
plain_text_path = input("Enter the input file name to encrypt: ")
encrypted_path = input("Enter the output file name to save code in: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
code = ""

with open(plain_text_path, mode='r') as file:
    plain_text = file.read()
print(plain_text)
for ch in plain_text:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue + distance
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - (ord('z') - ordValue + 1)
    code += chr(cipherValue)

with open(encrypted_path, "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(code)
```

decrypt:

```
file_path = input("Enter the input file name: ")
output_path = input("Enter the output file name: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
plainText = ''

with open(file_path, mode='r') as file:
    input_str = file.read()

for ch in input_str:
    ordValue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordValue - distance
    if cipherValue < ord('a'):
        cipherValue = ord('z') - (distance - (ordValue - ord('a')) - 1)
    plainText += chr(cipherValue)

with open(output_path, "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(plainText)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you. It worked for encryption but not for decryption. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nt-test-5d74a335", line 4, in <module>
    assert(org_contents == contents)
AssertionError

Comment: @chiggywiggy Be careful in giving the file name, Especially if it has an extension

Comment: what is this? `nt-test-5d74a335`?

Comment: this is just an exercise for class so it should be fine. and i'm not sure what that is. thtat was just the error message i got

Comment: @chiggywiggy how do you run python files?

Answer (score 0):

Oh...

It turns out that there was an error in the decrypt program since the coded text contains other characters and letters, which the decrypt.py file does not recognize since it examines the range of Unicode numbers involving smaller letters (referring to "if cipherValue < ord('a')").

To fix this, I have come up with these lines of code here which returns the new encrypted text, wherein each new character will be returned from the new number (Unicode no. of the recent character + shift or distance) via the chr function. Upon decoding the encrypted text, it will return what you have at the beginning. There is no need for letter case comparisons in these lines. :D

For encrypt.py:

```
input_file_name=input("Enter the input file you wanted to encrypt: ")
output_file_name = input("Save encrypted file as: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))

with open(input_file_name,"r") as file:
    plainText=file.read()

code = ""

for ch in plainText:
    new_ch=ch.replace(ch,chr(ord(ch)+distance))
    code+=new_ch

with open(output_file_name,"w") as new_file:
    new_file.write(code)
```

For decrypt.py:

```
input_file_name=input("Enter the input file you wanted to decrypt: ")
output_file_name = input("Save decrypted file as: ")
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))

with open(input_file_name,"r") as file:
    code=file.read()

plainText = ""

for ch in code:
    new_ch=ch.replace(ch,chr(ord(ch)-distance))
    plainText+=new_ch

with open(output_file_name,"w") as new_file:
    new_file.write(plainText)
```